# Why lists pksc11-tool seven Objects but Java Keystore has Only one

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#11, opensc, sunpkcs11

When I do  in the cmd line:

```
pkcs11-tool --login -O
```

I get seven Objects that are on my smartcard, 3 Public Key Objects, 3 Certificate Objects and one Private Key Object.

But when I try to do the same with a small Java Code, I only find one Certificate:

```
 String pkcs11Config = "name = SmartCard\nlibrary = opensc-pkcs11.dll\nslot=0";
  ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
  Provider prov = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(confStream);
  Security.addProvider(prov);
  String pin = "0000000";
  KeyStore cc = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", prov);
  cc.load(null, pin.toCharArray());

  // Look for certificate
  Enumeration aliases = cc.aliases();
  for (Enumeration e = aliases; e.hasMoreElements();) {
    Object alias = aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Alias is : " + alias);
  }
```

Why Do I found no Public key or other Certificate with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's standard behavior of JAVA's `SunPKCS11` provider. Its implementation is usually documented in *"PKCS#11 reference guide"*:

- [JDK 7 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)
- [JDK 8 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)
- [JDK 9 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm)
- [JDK 10 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm)

Pick a correct guide for your JAVA version and take a look at *"KeyStore requirements"* chapter.  You'll find out that SunPKCS11 provider returns aliases only for pairs of certificates and their matching private keys (that's one entry in your case) and ignores all other objects.